# upgrade to Rails 5.2: how to avoid "optional: true" for non-optional associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After moving my application from Rails 4.2.8 to 5.2.3 the inserts fail with

```
Billings event must exist
```

The application receives a single cascaded hash with one event and many associated billings and should put this into the database in *one* *single* *transaction*; this did always work before.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :billings, -> { where('1 = 1') }, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billings
  validates_associated :billings
end

class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event  
  validates_presence_of :event_id, on: :update
end

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def kC
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
       [doesn't get here anymore]
    end
  end
end
```

There is no controller for billings, they do only exist via their associated event.

Quick analyses finds in the docs mention that

```
belongs_to :event, optional: true
```

would avoid this error, and it indeed does. But this seems very wrong to me, because in this application billings must *never* exist without their event, it is *NOT* optional! 
But then, what is the correct solution?

Further analysis show: all validations get processed, but a before_create() callback is never reached. The "must exist" error is added at some internal place, it does not come from my code.

Furthermore, when creating a template with only the code as shown above, I found the problematic code to be the scoping `-> { where('1 = 1') }`

In the real application this is a more complex (and more useful) term, but this simple and seemingly transparent term triggers the problem just the same.

There are many similar questions here, but then, many have a situation where the association is indeed optional, some have nonstandard namings (I don't think I have, as it worked before), and I didn't find one for this case where the belonging model is fully handled via the having one.

Comment: The only change in Rails 5 is that it adds a presence validation to the the association by default. Which seems like something you actually want here. I don't think thats really the cause of your woes, rather its whatever callbacks and validations you have tacked on top of that that may not have worked properly in the first place since you are actually getting issues when the association does have a presence validation.

Comment: Due to Your suggestion, I removed all the 'whatever callbacks and validations' and was able to find that 'the only change in Rails 5' seems to have some non-desired effects. (Question updated accordingly.) I greatly appreciate an idea how this might be solved.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5, whenever we define a `belongs_to` association, it is required to have the associated record present by default. It triggers validation error if the associated record is not present. To remove this default behavior, we can use **new_framework_defaults.rb** initializer which comes with Rails 5.

(For more info you can check this https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937)

When upgrading from the older version of Rails to Rails 5, we can add this initializer by running `bin/rails app:update` task.

This newly added initializer has the following config flag that handles the default behavior

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

We can turn off this behavior by setting its value to **false**

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

Comment: Doesn't that initializer do just the same as setting `optional: true` ?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing. But the only difference is that it opting out this default behavior for the entire application.

Answer (score 2):

I found what appears to be the correct solution:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :billings, -> { where('1 = 1') }, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :event
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billings
  validates_associated :billings
end
```

Adding this `inverse_of:` option in this way resolves the problem.

*Preliminary tentative root cause analysis:*

The (sparse) documentation for the `inverse_of` option does suggest to add it to the `belongs_to` feature; it does not mention adding it to `has_many` (it does not discourage that either). Adding it to `belongs_to` does not improve things in this case, also the use-case in the documentation does not apply here.

Nevertheless, the documentation mentions an "automatic guessing" of associations, and that this automatic guessing would be omitted in certain cases as declared in `AssociationReflection::INVALID_AUTOMATIC_INVERSE_OPTIONS`.
Searching for this term in the source leads to a private method `can_find_inverse_of_automatically?()`, where it becomes obvious that also a *scope* will result in the automatic guessing being omitted.

It appears that the unravelling of a cumulative insert in some way needs to pinpoint the "inverse_of" (be it automatically or coded), or otherwise it would consider the owning relation as nonexisting - with the latter, due to the mentioned change in Rails 5, now leading to a validation error.